# keyup on iPad makes no difference between ( 0 and 9

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I have a script listening to inputs. 
On desktop browsers number keys can be detected listening to :

Example (jquery):

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[pattern]', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 && !e.shiftKey) {
        // do things
    }
}
```

On the ipad `e.shiftKey` is always `false` on the numeric keyboard.

I was thinking about using `e.originalEvent.keyIdentifier` but my IDE tells me it's depricated.

Any idea for on how to solve this?

Comment: I can't test on iOS device right now, but I think the most normalized way would be listening to `keypress` event where you have `e.charCode` from which you can detect the actual character being written, not just which key was pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/oswb6syy/

Comment: Problem is I need to use `keydown`, to `e.preventDefault()`. And with keydown `e.charCode` always return `0`